# MySql Stored Procedure Parameters - syntax error

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I want to create a .NET app using a Mysql database, parameters will be passed through C#.

Well, I learned how to create stored procedures in SQL Server, but I can't make it work in MySQL, the procedure is the following

```
create procedure uspInsertClient 

@Name varchar(100),
@Address varchar(100)

as
begin

insert into tbClients
(
Name,
Address
)
values
(
@Name,
@Address
)
end
```

I want to make this work on MySql, but it says @Parameter has a syntax error...

Any clue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See the applicable MySQL manual/reference. Nothing to do with C# or SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE uspInsertClient (Name_param varchar(100), Address_param varchar(100))
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO tbClients (name, address)
    VALUES (Name_param, Address_param);
END
```

[CREATE PROCEDURE and CREATE FUNCTION Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html).